# Unable to intersect lines on a floating bar chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts, amcharts5

I'm trying to build a chart, where every time floating bar top right corner should get intersect via line chart.

Below are some conditions:

- The line chart data won't get changed
- Bar should be modified as per the passed data so that they will get intersected on the edges.

I have tried something but not getting the idea on how to make it dynamic based on the data

I have tried amcharts floating and line chart mix

```
[codepen link](https://codepen.io/Vin_1991/pen/bGQabva)
```

Any kind of help would be much appreciated

[image: Sample chart image]

Comment: Please review your question and [edit] it in order to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added the code pen link